# Ошибка при компиляции Activity

Tags: java, android, activity

```
package org.WTFpro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
 
public class WTFproActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnActTwo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
    }

    public void goNewView(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnActTwo:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class WTFproActivity extends Activity {

Button mBtn;
   
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
 
        mBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn12);
        mBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

            @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
     Uri.parse("http://google.com")));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

К сожалению, только начинаю осваивать андроид, поэтому сразу прошу прощения, если вопрос глупый. Но при компиляции где-то в этом коде возникает ошибка. Подскажите, где она?

В логе указанно так:

> 1. ERROR in ***/projects/WTFpro/src/org/WTFpro/WTFproActivity.java (at line 34)   public class WTFproActivity extends Activity {
>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The type WTFproActivity is already defined

Comment: Чтобы понять, надо логи видеть. Их в LogCat смотреть надо. Но есть предположение, что у вас "NewActivity" ни в виде класса, ни в манифесте не объявлена.

Comment: WTFproActivity 2а одинаковых имени

Comment: @Denbka, "два одинаковых имени разных активностей", вы сиёзно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по логам:

Каждая активити должна объявляться в отдельном файле, иметь уникальное, неповторяющееся имя и должна быть указана в манифесте.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Разобрался, все работает.

Comment: @Denbka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Назовите 2 активность NewActivity. У вас используется 2 одинаковых имени

Comment: Переправил, не помогло. Теперь так:

1. ERROR in ****/projects/WTFpro/src/org/WTFpro/WTFproActivity.java (at line 34)
 public class NewActivity extends Activity {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
The public type NewActivity must be defined in its own file

и

2. ERROR in ****/projects/WTFpro/src/org/WTFpro/NewActivity.java (at line 6)
 public class NewActivity extends Activity {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
The type NewActivity is already defined

Comment: @Denbka, http://translate.google.com